# Signal Processing made viral on social media?

Tags: discussion, scope

[tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com) is active on Twitter, see for instance: [Are ^ and _ the only commands in LaTeX not preceded by a backslash?](https://twitter.com/StackTeX/status/1187111610244055048)

Since StackExchange communities are quite different in behavior, do you wish we get active on social media, like Twitter? @StackSignalProcessing seems available as of today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We already have [@stacksignals](https://twitter.com/stacksignals) on Twitter.

Comment: Total discovery, how could I have missed it?

Comment: I wonder what it tweets.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo Your guess is as good as mine!